# Trouble deduplicating "double" ga4 events

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We have migrated our tracking to ga4. We have a custom conversion event (a submission on our website). We are using `gtag` and firing the event only once on the page.

See image below:

[image]

However, in https://tagassistant.google.com I can see **two** events firing to the ga4 container.

One event looks like the code on the page and does not "send a hit", see below:

[image]

The second event includes a `send_to` key and is the only event which "sends a hit" as can be seen here:

[image]

I am completely stumped as to why this event is "firing twice".

Comment: For those who will answer with the question "have you included gtm or the ga4 tag twice on the page" the answer is definitely not. I have followed all the steps on this excellent article: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/duplicate-events-in-google-analytics-4-and-how-to-fix-them/

Answer (score 0):

It is only UI confusing people.

Check with the debug_view or you can check the network request that send to GA4.

It should only fire once. The UI in "https://tagassistant.google.com" you can just take care the `hits send` tab.

If there is only one request about this event. Then nothing duplicate.